# Getting Data from Bitsnoop API

Tags: php, json, url, curl

I am using the following piece of code to get tracker data (converted from JSON to PHP) and find the sum total of the number of seeders from the [BitSnoop API](http://bitsnoop.com/api/trackers.php?hash=98C5C361D0BE5F2A07EA8FA5052E5AA48097E7F6&json=1):

```
$hash = "98C5C361D0BE5F2A07EA8FA5052E5AA48097E7F6";

if(!function_exists("curl_init")) die("cURL extension is not installed");
$url = "http://bitsnoop.com/api/trackers.php?hash=" . $hash . "&json=1";
echo $url;
$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$r=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$myarr = json_decode($r,true);
print_r($myarr);
```

But the script is not able to retrieve ANY data from the URL.

Chrome's view-source is working on the [page](http://bitsnoop.com/api/trackers.php?hash=98C5C361D0BE5F2A07EA8FA5052E5AA48097E7F6&json=1), but any other way of retrieving the source of the page, either via [viewsource.in](http://viewsource.in) or [i-tools](http://i-tools.org/unserialize) don't seem to retrieve any data from the URL as well.

Could anyone explain why is it so?
And please provide an alternative way to accomplish the retrieval.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pretend to be a legit browser:

```
$hash = "98C5C361D0BE5F2A07EA8FA5052E5AA48097E7F6";

if(!function_exists("curl_init")) die("cURL extension is not installed");
$url = "http://bitsnoop.com/api/trackers.php?hash=" . $hash . "&json=1";

$headers = array(
'Host: bitsnoop.com',
'Connection: keep-alive',
'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36',
'Accept-Encoding: deflate,sdch',
'Accept-Language: ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6');

echo $url;
$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$r=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$myarr = json_decode($r,true);
print_r($myarr);
```

And also it's a good idea to test `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` , however, I did not look if they use or not HTTP redirect

Comment: Could you add a little explanation for the headers ?

Comment: It works but I would really like some info on the various parameters of the headers. :)

Comment: have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields , but in order to thoroughly understand every header, read RFC. I just copied them from Network tab of Chrome. I don't know which of them is necessary, but you can experiment by removing one-by-one and testing.